# How to select rows from two different Numpy arrays conditionally?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have two Numpy 2D arrays and I want to get a single 2D array by selecting rows from the original two arrays. The selection is done conditionally. Here is the simple Python way,

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([4, 0, 1, 2, 4])
b = np.array([0, 4, 3, 2, 0])
y = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 0]])
x = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 0]])
z = np.empty(shape=x.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    z[i] = y[i] if a[i] >= b[i] else x[i]

print(z)
```

Looking at [numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), I tried, `np.select([a >= b, a < b], [y, x], -1)` but got `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (5,) and arg 1 with shape (5, 4).`

Could someone help me write this in a more efficient Numpy manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, but it would be helpful if you could show an example of your expected output:

```py
>>> np.where((a >= b)[:, None], y, x)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Your output is as expected. Could do with a little explanation though.

Comment: The `[:, None]` adds a new axis to the boolean mask array `a >= b` -- which makes it suitable for applying to the multidimensional arrays `x` and `y`. I'm not actually 100% sure how `np.where` operates under the hood, since normal advanced indexing with a 1D array works on a 2D array... Somebody more qualified could give a better explanation of why the broadcast-ability is required in `np.where`.

Comment: Is `[:, None]` the same as `[:, -1]`?

Comment: No. The `None` creates a new axis where one wasn't previous.  It's shorthand for [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis). Using `[:, -1]` on a 1D array would give an `IndexError` because there's only one axis in a 1D array.